# How to receive id token by HTTPS POST with Python Backend?

Tags: google-app-engine, https, xmlhttprequest, urllib2, google-signin

I am starting on back-end and API handling and would appreciate some pointers, resources or tips with how to receive a token by HTTPS POST using Python.

I am following the Sign-in tutorial on Google's developer page ([Google sign-in Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)).

Using JavaScript I am able to `getBasicProfile()` information but the tutorial recommends not to communicate with my back-end via this profile object. Instead they instruct to authenticate by sending the ID token with an HTTPS POST request.

The first connection with the API (I believe) is made with JavaScript upon the user click on the sign-in button:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  ...
}
```

Then, they send the token like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/tokensignin');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
```

My doubt is really, what to do on my Python Backend to get this id_token (and not via a Cookie-set)?

The tutorial instructs:

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

# (Receive token by HTTPS POST)
# ...                        <== this is where I am at a loss!! Beginner tutorial??

try:
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)

    if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
        raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

    # Valid ID token. Get user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
    userid = idinfo['sub']
except ValueError:
    # Invalid token
    pass
```

(EDIT):

**WHAT I HAVE ATTEMPTED**

My understanding is that by using the `xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);` I would be posting a new header with the id_token to the URL declared in `xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/tokensignin');`

However, my attempt so far is to try to read the headers posted to this URL by using the `urllib2` library in python.

So, on my `main.py` file I try to see if the new header has been posted like:

```
import urllib2

class Glogin(webapp2.RequestHandler): # url will be '/glogin'
  def get(self):
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/tokensignin'
    try:
        # Write the headers out (I expect to see '(idtoken, id_token)' now included) 
        result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        self.response.out.write(result.headers.items())

    except urllib2.URLError:
        logging.exception('Caught exception fetching url')
```

However, what I find is only those headers that were there before (i.e. idtoken was never posted by the JS send() method??):

```
[('cache-control', 'no-cache'), ('content-length', '6870'), ('server', 'Development/2.0'), ('date', 'Fri, 19 Jan 2018 06:17:45 GMT'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), ('connection', 'close')]
```

Comment: Have you find the solution? I am looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `token` variable before you get to your
`try` statement.
You can use Flask's `request` and catch the token as follows:

```
token = request.form["idtoken"]
```

So your final code looks something like this:

```
token = request.form["idtoken"]
try:
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)

    if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
        raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

    # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
    userid = idinfo['sub']
except ValueError:
    # Invalid token
    pass
```

Late reply but I just finished banging my head over this and I thought others might find this useful in the future.